# Pine scripts Version 4 time intervals

Tags: pine-script

I used this command and works in version 2 or 3.
But that doesn't work in version 4.
May I know how to alter and make it work in version 4 please?
Thanks

```
hmalen1 = not isintraday ? "180" :
     (interval <= 5) ? "2" :
     (interval <= 10) ? "2" : 
     (interval <= 15) ? "3" : 
     (interval <= 30) ? "5" : 
     (interval <= 60) ? "10" : 
     (interval <= 90) ? "15" : 
     (interval <= 120) ? "20" :
```

Answer (score 0):

use `timeframe.isintraday` and `timeframe.multiplier` instead